# Why is a struct with a deleted copy constructor not a POD type?

Tags: c++, struct, c++14, copy-constructor

We have the following method to test if our structure is a POD or not.  It always returns true:

```
bool podTest() {
  struct podTest {
    int count;
    int x[];
  };

  return std::is_pod<podTest>::value;  //Always returns true
}
```

So far so good.  Now we make one change and delete the copy constructor:

```
bool podTest() {
  struct podTest {
    podTest(const podTest&) = delete;
    int count;
    int x[];
  };

  return std::is_pod<podTest>::value;  //Always returns false
}
```

This always returns false.  After reading over the definition of `is_pod` I am still struggling to understand what requirement it violates.  What am I missing?

This is being compiled on godbolt using gcc 6.1, with `-std=c++14`

Comment: At a guess because you are saying the struct cannot be copied, but one of the qualities of POD types is that they are always copyable.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: One of the requirements of POD types is, that they are **trivially** copyable.

Comment: Oddly enough, `std::is_trivially_copyable<podTest>::value` returns true, so there must be some other violation of POD requirements. Certainly `int x[];` should be removed. Unless I'm mistaken, flexible array bounds aren't part of C++14.

Comment: @IInspectable libstdc++ implements `std::is_pod` with a compiler hook it seems, not via the `std::is_trivially_copyable`. libc++ also uses the compiler hook if available, but its fallback implementation is wrong too because Trivially Copyable is not the same as (Trivially Copy Constructible && Trivially Copy Assignable), which is what they check for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aha!

From [class]:

> A POD struct is a non-union class that is both **a trivial class** and a standard-layout class

where a trivial class is:

> A *trivial class* is a class that is trivially copyable and **has one or more default constructors (12.1), all of which
>   are either trivial or deleted and at least one of which is not deleted.**

But in [class.copy]:

> **If there is
>   no user-declared constructor** for class `X`, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

Your `podTest`, when you explicitly deleted the copy constructor, has no default constructor. So it's not a trivial class, so it's not a POD. If you add in:

```
podTest() = default;
```

Then it'll become a POD again.

Comment: So in this case, a class without a copy constructor can still be copied with memcpy()!

Comment: If there are two default ctors, with one deleted and one not. Is there not an ambiguity if you try to create an object of the class? I wonder about the reason for this "at least one non-deleted" rule.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It's possible to be non-ambiguous: `struct X { X() = default; template <class... Args> X(Args&&...) = delete; }; X x;`

Comment: @Barry correct, but the text makes even the ambiguous cases PODs. And if you placed the `= delete` onto the non-template and didn't delete the other template default-ctor, it would still have marked it as a POD.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yeah I don't know. It seems like a very specific wording choice.

Answer (score 2):

Because deleted copy constructors are allowed for POD types only after C++14. I would assume, you are compiling your code in C++11 mode.

Comment: The `struct` above is trivially copyable in both C++11 and C++14, and according to cppr, that's all the copy semantics we need for POD.

Comment: It's so strange to me that a noncopyable type can be POD. I thought POD types were supposed to have the same behaviour in C and C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, is this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable wrong than?

Comment: @SergeyA Probably. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759441/is-a-class-with-deleted-copy-constructor-trivially-copyable Edit: No, I don't think so. Looks a little inprecise at most.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, i think, this answer is outdated..?

Comment: @SergeyA You mean in the question I linked? That handles both C++11 and C++14, so I don't think so.

Comment: I've edited the question to specify the compiler/language version since it appears to be relevant.

Comment: Actually, I cannot find the update from the CWG fix T.C. cites in N4141; the rules there seem to match C++11. So either there is a major difference between N4141 or the entire C++14 part on Trivial Types, including trivially copyable, is just wrong.

Comment: Had to dv, Barry found the correct reason, proving this answer wrong.

Comment: @Brian `struct X { X(X const&) = delete; }` is trivially copyable. I love C++. Then again, you can't really have a noncopyable type in C right?

Comment: @Barry And indeed, you are allowed to memcpy struct X, as it is trivially copyable, even when the copy constructor is deleted. It doesn't feel right, though.