# Why std::atomic is not trivial type in only Visual C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

The Folly library requires that `std::atomic<hazptr_obj*>` should be a trivial type. This works with gcc and clang, but failing for Visual C++ even for `std::atomic<int>`. Why does `std::is_trivial` return `false`?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <atomic>

static_assert(
    std::is_trivial<std::atomic<int>>::value,
    "std::atomic<int> not trivial");
```

Comment: Related: [trivial vs. standard layout vs. POD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6496545/712526)

Comment: I was under the impression that a trivial type had to be trivially copyable, while `std::atomic` types are not copyable.

Comment: I'm curious -- did you put in the `static_assert`, or did the library authors do this?  If it's the authors, then they must have had some knowledge that `std::atomic` is not guaranteed to pass the `std::is_trivial` test.

Comment: `std::atomic` used to be trivial, but isn't anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759556/3002139 for a great and detailed explanation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/8635022f0c4005dc218dd74cdee768126c954763/folly/experimental/hazptr/hazptr-impl.h#L316-L318

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks. You can post it as answer. Good enough for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::atomic` used to be trivial (which requires Trivially Copyable), but isn't anymore. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29759556/3002139) for a great and detailed explanation for how and why that changed.

This makes VC compliant and gcc and clang non-compliant at least in C++17. As this was considered a defect by the committee, VC shows the desired behavior for C++11 and C++14, too.

For future reference, the relevant defect is [DR #1734](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1734), you can see the implementation status for clang [here](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html). I'm not aware of an equivalent status page for gcc.

Answer (score 1):

The assert in `folly` was disabled for MSVC in https://github.com/facebook/folly/commit/a47a5531edcb95a27f987e810272ba94a9b51162

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about the Folly library, but having the assertion for some compilers but not all seems obviously wrong.  Either the library depends on triviality, in which case the assertion should stay and prevent building on corrected toolchains until the library is changed to work right with the new behavior (although it should move so it doesn't affect users who merely include the file), or the library doesn't require triviality, in which case the assertion is wrong on all compilers.  Am I missing something?