# C++ Object Array Initialization without Copy Constructor

Tags: c++

I had the following class:

```
class A  
{  
public:  
    A(int i)  
        :m_n{i}  
    {
        std::cout << "A(int)\n";
    }
    // I don't need copy constructor.
    A(const A&) = delete;

private:
    int m_n;
};
```

Then I declared an array of A:

```
int main()
{
    A aa[] {1, 2, 3};

    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile the program on OnlineGDB
(https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) using C++14, I got the 
following error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':  
main.cpp:38:20: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'  
     A aa[] {1, 2, 3};  
                    ^  
main.cpp:22:5: note: declared here
     A(const A&) = delete;
     ^
main.cpp:16:5: note:   after user-defined conversion: A::A(int)
     A(int i)
     ^
```

Then I add copy constructor to class A:

```
A(const A& a)
    :m_n{a.m_n}
{
    std::cout << "A(const A&)\n"
}
```

and the program compiled and output the following:

```
A::A(int)
A::A(int)
```

My question:
since the copy constructor was never called, why shall I define it?

Comment: It's part of an optimization called [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) where copy-construction is *elided* (the copy constructor is not called). ***But*** the copy constructor still needs to exist for it to be possible, since not all copying can be elided (optimized away).

Comment: In C++17 it is unnecessary though, the elision is guaranteed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759441/is-a-class-with-deleted-copy-constructor-trivially-copyable
This might help you